# Contatenate 3 data in 1

Tags: php

Good day, I want to join 3 tables in one, is my code right?

```html
<?php echo htmlentities($dn1['itrf_type'+'itrf_details'+'rfv_details'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? This is very unclear.

Comment: PHP !== JS. PHP uses `.` to concatenate

Comment: Even if you use . instead of + this still makes no sense. I'm guessing you don't want `$dn1['itrf_typeitrf_detailsrfv_details']`. Maybe you're looking for `$dn1['itrf_type'] . $dn1['itrf_details'] . $dn1['rfv_details'],`

Comment: great ! thank you for helping!